# When should I use ConcurrentSkipListMap?

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, dictionary, concurrenthashmap

In Java, `ConcurrentHashMap` is there for better `multithreading` solution. Then when should I use `ConcurrentSkipListMap`? Is it a redundancy?

Does multithreading aspects between these two are common?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

These two classes vary in a few ways.

[ConcurrentHashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) does not guarantee* the runtime of its operations as part of its contract.  It also allows tuning for certain load factors (roughly, the number of threads concurrently modifying it).

[ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html), on the other hand, guarantees average O(log(n)) performance on a wide variety of operations.  It also does not support tuning for concurrency's sake.  `ConcurrentSkipListMap` also has a number of operations that `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't: ceilingEntry/Key, floorEntry/Key, etc.  It also maintains a sort order, which would otherwise have to be calculated (at notable expense) if you were using a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Basically, different implementations are provided for different use cases.  If you need quick single key/value pair addition and quick single key lookup, use the `HashMap`.  If you need faster in-order traversal, and can afford the extra cost for insertion, use the `SkipListMap`.

<sub>*Though I expect the implementation is roughly in line with the general hash-map guarantees of O(1) insertion/lookup; ignoring re-hashing</sub>

Comment: Ok. Log(n) is fine but does ConcurrentSkipListMap is space efficient?

Comment: Skip lists are necessarily larger than Hashtables, but the tunable nature of ConcurrentHashMap makes it possible to construct a Hashtable that is larger than the equivalent ConcurrentSkipListMap.  In general, I'd expect the skip list to be larger but on the same order of magnitude.

Comment: "It also does not support tuning for concurrency's sake".. Why? What is the link?

Comment: @Pacerier - I didn't mean it does support tuning because it's concurrent, I mean it doesn't allow you to tune parameters that influence it's concurrent performance (while ConcurrentHashMap does).

Comment: @KevinMontrose Ic, so you meant "It also does not support concurrency tuning."

Comment: I find it odd that everyone likes to compare time complexity in the absence of required space.  SkipLists are much more memory efficient (a point that I think is worth noting)

Answer (score 18):

## Sorted, navigable, and concurrent

See [Skip List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) for a definition of the data structure.

A [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) stores the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) in the natural order of its keys (or some other key order you define).  So it'll have slower `get`/`put`/`contains` operations than a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html), but to offset this it supports the [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html), [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html), and [`ConcurrentNavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentNavigableMap.html) interfaces.

Answer (score 13):

> Then when should I use ConcurrentSkipListMap?

When you (a) need to keep keys sorted, and/or (b) need the first/last, head/tail, and submap features of a navigable map.

The [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) class implements the [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) interface, as does [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html). But if you also want the behaviors of [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) and [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html), use [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)

## `ConcurrentHashMap`

- ❌ Sorted
- ❌ Navigable
- ✅ Concurrent

## `ConcurrentSkipListMap`

- ✅ Sorted
- ✅ Navigable
- ✅ Concurrent

Here is table guiding you through the major features of the various [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) implementations bundled with Java 11. Click/tap to zoom.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

Keep in mind that you can obtain other [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) implementations, and similar such data structures, from other sources such as [*Google Guava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava).

Comment: This picture is awesome. Do you have similar pictures for some or all of normal and concurrent collections?

Comment: @Anv Thanks, making that chart took quite a bit of work. It is part of my presentation for Java user groups: *A map to Java Maps*. And, No, I’ve made just one other class diagram, [for `String` related classes and interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26498954/642706).

Answer (score 9):

In terms of performance, `skipList` when is used as Map - appears to be 10-20 times slower. Here is the result of my tests (Java 1.8.0_102-b14, win x32)

```
Benchmark                    Mode  Cnt  Score    Error  Units
MyBenchmark.hasMap_get       avgt    5  0.015 ?  0.001   s/op
MyBenchmark.hashMap_put      avgt    5  0.029 ?  0.004   s/op
MyBenchmark.skipListMap_get  avgt    5  0.312 ?  0.014   s/op
MyBenchmark.skipList_put     avgt    5  0.351 ?  0.007   s/op
```

And additionally to that - use-case where comparing one-to-another really makes sense. Implementation of the cache of last-recently-used items using both of these collections. Now efficiency of skipList looks to be event more dubious.

```
MyBenchmark.hashMap_put1000_lru      avgt    5  0.032 ?  0.001   s/op
MyBenchmark.skipListMap_put1000_lru  avgt    5  3.332 ?  0.124   s/op
```

Here is the code for JMH (executed as `java -jar target/benchmarks.jar -bm avgt -f 1 -wi 5 -i 5 -t 1`)

```
static final int nCycles = 50000;
static final int nRep = 10;
static final int dataSize = nCycles / 4;
static final List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(nCycles);
static final Map<String,String> hmap4get = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(3000, 0.5f, 10);
static final Map<String,String> smap4get = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();

static {
    // prepare data
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(dataSize);
    for( int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++ ) {
        values.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }
    // rehash data for all cycles
    for( int i = 0; i < nCycles; i++ ) {
        data.add(values.get((int)(Math.random() * dataSize)));
    }
    // rehash data for all cycles
    for( int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++ ) {
        String value = data.get((int)(Math.random() * dataSize));
        hmap4get.put(value, value);
        smap4get.put(value, value);
    }
}

@Benchmark
public void skipList_put() {
    for( int n = 0; n < nRep; n++ ) {
        Map<String,String> map = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();

        for( int i = 0; i < nCycles; i++ ) {
            String key = data.get(i);
            map.put(key, key);
        }
    }
}

@Benchmark
public void skipListMap_get() {
    for( int n = 0; n < nRep; n++ ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < nCycles; i++ ) {
            String key = data.get(i);
            smap4get.get(key);
        }
    }
}

@Benchmark
public void hashMap_put() {
    for( int n = 0; n < nRep; n++ ) {
        Map<String,String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(3000, 0.5f, 10);

        for( int i = 0; i < nCycles; i++ ) {
            String key = data.get(i);
            map.put(key, key);
        }
    }
}

@Benchmark
public void hasMap_get() {
    for( int n = 0; n < nRep; n++ ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < nCycles; i++ ) {
            String key = data.get(i);
            hmap4get.get(key);
        }
    }
}

@Benchmark
public void skipListMap_put1000_lru() {
    int sizeLimit = 1000;

    for( int n = 0; n < nRep; n++ ) {
        ConcurrentSkipListMap<String,String> map = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();

        for( int i = 0; i < nCycles; i++ ) {
            String key = data.get(i);
            String oldValue = map.put(key, key);

            if( (oldValue == null) && map.size() > sizeLimit ) {
                // not real lru, but i care only about performance here
                map.remove(map.firstKey());
            }
        }
    }
}

@Benchmark
public void hashMap_put1000_lru() {
    int sizeLimit = 1000;
    Queue<String> lru = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(sizeLimit + 50);

    for( int n = 0; n < nRep; n++ ) {
        Map<String,String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(3000, 0.5f, 10);

        lru.clear();
        for( int i = 0; i < nCycles; i++ ) {
            String key = data.get(i);
            String oldValue = map.put(key, key);

            if( (oldValue == null) && lru.size() > sizeLimit ) {
                map.remove(lru.poll());
                lru.add(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think ConcurrentSkipListMap should be compared to their non-concurrent counter part, the TreeMap.

Comment: As abbas commented, comparing performance to ConcurrentHashMap seems silly. The purpose of ConcurrentSkipListMap is to (a) provide concurrency, and (b) maintain sort-order amongst the keys. ConcurrentHashMap does a, but not b. Comparing the 0-to-60 speed of a Tesla and a dump truck is senseless, as they serve different purposes.

Comment: While you don't know performance metrics you don't know which one is Tesla and which one is "dump truck" :) Also ... you do not know the price of "b" without metrics. Therefore - comparing performance is generally useful thing.

Comment: Maybe add a comparison to tree map! :D

Comment: Skip lists are much more memory efficient.  For me that's more important than a few milliseconds in lookups.

Comment: It feels a little bit weird to benchmark the performance of a datastructure meant for concurrent access only single threaded. This would be more interesting with more threads (even just `-tc 1,2,4,8` to see performance with 1, 2, 4, 8 threads). I expect concurrent hashmap (even with the default config) would trounce concurrent skip list map, but the curve in vertical scalability could be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Based on workloads ConcurrentSkipListMap could be slower than TreeMap with synchronized methods as in [KAFKA-8802](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8802) if range queries are needed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I am justing thinking to replace TreeMap with ConcurrentSkipListMap in one of my project, so it is good to know this! Do you have more context about why ConcurrentSkipListMap is slower, and more detail about performance comparison?

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentHashMap : when u want multithreaded index based get/put, only index based operations are supported. Get/Put are of O(1)

ConcurrentSkipListMap : More operations than just get/put, like sorted top/bottom n items by key, get last entry, fetch/traverse whole map sorted by key etc. Complexity is of O(log(n)), So put performance is not as great as ConcurrentHashMap. It't an implementation of ConcurrentNavigableMap with SkipList.

To summarize use ConcurrentSkipListMap when you want to do more operations on map requiring sorted features rather than just simple get and put.