# Exact difference between CharSequence and String in java

Tags: java, string, charsequence

I read this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600635/what-is-the-difference-between-charsequence-and-a-string). Can any one say what the exact difference between `CharSequence` and String is, other than the fact that [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) implements [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) and that `String` is a sequence of character? For example:

```
CharSequence obj = "hello";
String str = "hello";
System.out.println("output is : " + obj + "  " + str);
```

What happens when "hello" is assigned to `obj` and again to `str` ?

Comment: This is going to sound very RTFMish, but it's an honest advice: it can be very interesting and a learning experience to actually look at the source code for String yourself

Comment: Where can you find the Java source code? I thought it was all proprietary?

Comment: @aaronsnoswell: OpenJDK is open source. You can find one version of the `String` class at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/6069fe8ffead/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java. But even before that, Sun JDKs used to come with a file called `src.zip` which contained much of the source code. Looking at that code was possible and useful, although modifying it was probably another matter, in terms of license.

Comment: For source code, multiple companies provide access through their own web sites to various open source projects including OpenJDK. Simply **use a search engine** for a query such as "java string class source code" to get multiple hits on those providers.

Comment: Similar to: [*Why StringBuilder when there is String?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5234147/642706)

Comment: Oh my god, does Oracle no longer release the source  with their JDK?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

### General differences

There are several classes which implement the [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface besides [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html). Among these are

- [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for variable-length character sequences which can be modified
- [`CharBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/CharBuffer.html) for fixed-length low-level character sequences which can be modified

Any method which accepts a `CharSequence` can operate on all of these equally well. Any method which only accepts a `String` will require conversion. So using `CharSequence` as an argument type in all the places where you don't care about the internals is prudent. However you should use `String` as a return type if you actually return a `String`, because that avoids possible conversions of returned values if the calling method actually does require a `String`.

Also note that maps should use `String` as key type, not `CharSequence`, as map keys must not change. In other words, sometimes the immutable nature of `String` is essential.

### Specific code snippet

As for the code you pasted: simply compile that, and have a look at the JVM bytecode using `javap -v`. There you will notice that both `obj` and `str` are references to the same constant object. As a `String` is immutable, this kind of sharing is all right.

The `+` operator of `String` is compiled as invocations of various `StringBuilder.append` calls. So it is equivalent to

```
System.out.println(
  (new StringBuilder())
  .append("output is : ")
  .append((Object)obj)
  .append(" ")
  .append(str)
  .toString()
)
```

I must confess I'm a bit surprised that my compiler `javac 1.6.0_33` compiles the `+ obj` using `StringBuilder.append(Object)` instead of `StringBuilder.append(CharSequence)`. The former probably involves a call to the `toString()` method of the object, whereas the latter should be possible in a more efficient way. On the other hand, `String.toString()` simply returns the `String` itself, so there is little penalty there. So  `StringBuilder.append(String)` might be more efficient by about one method invocation.

Answer (score 99):

## tl;dr

One is an interface ([`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)) while other is a concrete implementation of that interface ([`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)).

```
CharSequence animal = "cat"  // `String` object presented as the interface `CharSequence`.
```

Just like [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html), and [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) is a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html), so too `String` is a `CharSequence`.

As an interface, normally the `CharSequence` would be more commonly seen than `String`, but some twisted history resulted in the interface being defined years *after* the implementation. So in older APIs we often see `String` while in newer APIs we tend to see `CharSequence` used to define arguments and return types.

## Details

Nowadays we know that generally an API/framework should focus on exporting interfaces primarily and concrete classes secondarily. But we did not always know this lesson so well.

The `String` class came first in Java. Only later did they place a front-facing interface, `CharSequence`.

### Twisted History

A little history might help with understanding.

In its early days, Java was rushed to market a bit ahead of its time, due to the Internet/Web mania animating the industry. Some libraries were not as well thought-through as they should have been. String handling was one of those areas.

Also, Java was one of the earliest production-oriented non-academic [Object-Oriented Programming (OOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) environments. The only successful real-world rubber-meets-the-road implementations of OOP before that was some limited versions of [SmallTalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk), then [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) with [NeXTSTEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXTSTEP)/[OpenStep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStep). So, many practical lessons were yet to be learned.

Java started with the [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class and [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) class. But those two classes were unrelated, not tied to each other by inheritance nor interface. Later, the Java team recognized that there should have been a unifying tie between string-related implementations to make them interchangeable. In Java 4 the team added the [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface and retroactively implemented that interface on String and String Buffer, as well as adding another implementation [`CharBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html). Later in Java 5 they added [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), basically a unsynchronized and therefore somewhat faster version of `StringBuffer`.

So these string-oriented classes are a bit of a mess, and a little confusing to learn about. Many libraries and interfaces were built to take and return `String` objects. Nowadays such libraries should generally be built to expect `CharSequence`. But (a) `String` seems to still dominate the mindspace, and (b) there may be some subtle technical issues when mixing the various `CharSequence` implementations. With the 20/20 vision of hindsight we can see that all this string stuff could have been better handled, but here we are.

Ideally Java would have started with an interface and/or superclass that would be used in many places where we now use `String`, just as we use the [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) or [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interfaces in place of the [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implementations.

### Interface Versus Class

The key difference about `CharSequence` is that it is an [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)), not an [implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementation). That means you cannot directly instantiate a `CharSequence`. Rather you instantiate one of the classes that implements that interface.

For example, here we have `x` that looks like a `CharSequence` but underneath is actually a `StringBuilder` object.

```
CharSequence x = new StringBuilder( "dog" );  // Looks like a `CharSequence` but is actually a `StringBuilder` instance.
```

This becomes less obvious when using a String literal. Keep in mind that when you see source code with just quote marks around characters, the compiler is translating that into a String object.

```
CharSequence y = "cat";  // Looks like a `CharSequence` but is actually a `String` instance.
```

### Literal versus constructor

There are some subtle differences between `"cat"` and `new String("cat")` as discussed in [this other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java), but are irrelevant here.

### Class Diagram

This class diagram may help to guide you. I noted the version of Java in which they appeared to demonstrate how much change has churned through these classes and interfaces.

[image: diagram showing the various string-related classes and interfaces as of Java 8]

### Text Blocks

Other than adding more [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters including a multitude of [emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji), in recent years not much has changed in Java for working with text. Until *text blocks*.

Text blocks are a new way of better handling the tedium of string literals with multiple lines or [character-escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). This would make writing embedded code strings such as HTML, XML, SQL, or JSON much more convenient.

To quote [JEP 378](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378):

> A text block is a multi-line string literal that avoids the need for most escape sequences, automatically formats the string in a predictable way, and gives the developer control over the format when desired.

The text blocks feature does *not* introduce a new [data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type). Text blocks are merely a new syntax for writing a `String` literal. A text block produces a `String` object, just like the conventional literal syntax. A text block produces a `String` object, which is also a `CharSequence` object, as discussed above.

#### SQL example

To quote JSR 378 again…

Using "one-dimensional" string literals.

```
String query = "SELECT \"EMP_ID\", \"LAST_NAME\" FROM \"EMPLOYEE_TB\"\n" +
               "WHERE \"CITY\" = 'INDIANAPOLIS'\n" +
               "ORDER BY \"EMP_ID\", \"LAST_NAME\";\n";
```

Using a "two-dimensional" block of text

```
String query = """
               SELECT "EMP_ID", "LAST_NAME" FROM "EMPLOYEE_TB"
               WHERE "CITY" = 'INDIANAPOLIS'
               ORDER BY "EMP_ID", "LAST_NAME";
               """;
```

Text blocks are found in [Java 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_15) and later, per [*JEP 378: Text Blocks*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378).

First previewed in Java 13, under [JEP 355: Text Blocks (Preview)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/355). Then previewed again in Java 14 under [*JEP 368: Text Blocks (Second Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/368).

This effort was preceded by [*JEP 326: Raw String Literals (Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/326). The concepts were reworked to produce the *Text Blocks* feature instead.

### String templates

String templates complement Java's existing string literals and text blocks by coupling literal text with embedded expressions and template processors to produce specialized results.

See [*JEP 430: String Templates (Preview)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430).

This feature is being previewed in Java 21.

Comment: the old good school

Comment: Awesome , i read some of you other answers and i was thinking how does that guy knows that much , all are long and well explained did you find a way to download information into your brain :)

Answer (score 22):

`CharSequence` is a contract ([interface](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing))), and `String` is an [implementation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementation#Computer_science) of this contract.

```
public final class String extends Object 
    implements Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
```

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) for `CharSequence` is:

> A CharSequence is a readable sequence of char values. This interface
>   provides uniform, read-only access to many different kinds of char
>   sequences. A char value represents a character in the Basic
>   Multilingual Plane (BMP) or a surrogate. Refer to Unicode Character
>   Representation for details.

Answer (score 12):

> other than the fact that String implements CharSequence and that String is a sequence of character.

Several things happen in your code:

```
CharSequence obj = "hello";
```

That creates a `String` literal, `"hello"`, which is a `String` object. Being a `String`, which implements `CharSequence`, it is also a `CharSequence`. (you can read [this post about coding to interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194278/should-you-always-code-to-interfaces-in-java) for example).

The next line:

```
String str = "hello";
```

is a little more complex. `String` literals in Java are held in a pool (interned) so the `"hello"` on this line is the same object (identity) as the `"hello"` on the first line. Therefore, this line only assigns the same `String` literal to `str`.

At this point, both `obj` and `str` are references to the `String` literal `"hello"` and are therefore `equals`, `==` and they are both a `String` and a `CharSequence`.

I suggest you test this code, showing in action what I just wrote:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CharSequence obj = "hello";
    String str = "hello";
    System.out.println("Type of obj: " + obj.getClass().getSimpleName());
    System.out.println("Type of str: " + str.getClass().getSimpleName());
    System.out.println("Value of obj: " + obj);
    System.out.println("Value of str: " + str);
    System.out.println("Is obj a String? " + (obj instanceof String));
    System.out.println("Is obj a CharSequence? " + (obj instanceof CharSequence));
    System.out.println("Is str a String? " + (str instanceof String));
    System.out.println("Is str a CharSequence? " + (str instanceof CharSequence));
    System.out.println("Is \"hello\" a String? " + ("hello" instanceof String));
    System.out.println("Is \"hello\" a CharSequence? " + ("hello" instanceof CharSequence));
    System.out.println("str.equals(obj)? " + str.equals(obj));
    System.out.println("(str == obj)? " + (str == obj));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it a kind of obvious, but CharSequence is an interface whereas String is a concrete class :)

java.lang.String is an implementation of this interface...

Answer (score 2):

From the Java API of [CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html):

> A CharSequence is a readable sequence of characters. This interface provides uniform, read-only access to many different kinds of character sequences.

This interface is then used by [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), [CharBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) and [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) to keep consistency for all method names.

Answer (score 2):

Consider UTF-8. In UTF-8 Unicode code points are built from one or more bytes. A class encapsulating a UTF-8 byte array can implement the CharSequence interface but is most decidedly not a String. Certainly you can't pass a UTF-8 byte array where a String is expected but you certainly can pass a UTF-8 wrapper class that implements CharSequence when the contract is relaxed to allow a CharSequence. On my project, I am developing a class called CBTF8Field (Compressed Binary Transfer Format - Eight Bit) to provide data compression for xml and am looking to use the CharSequence interface to implement conversions from CBTF8 byte arrays to/from character arrays (UTF-16) and byte arrays (UTF-8).

The reason I came here was to get a complete understanding of the subsequence contract.

Answer (score 1):

In charSequence you don't have very useful methods which are available for String. If you don't want to look in the documentation, type:
   obj.
and
   str.

and see what methods your compilator offers you. That's the basic difference for me.