# Difference Between StringBuffer(String str) and StringBuffer(CharSequence chars)

Tags: java, string

1.I am confused between these two,Do they have different functionality if so then How ?

```
StringBuffer(CharSequence chars)
```

and

```
StringBuffer(String str)
```

2. What is basic Difference between String And CharSequence(Specially functionality) ?

Comment: Good catch, I thought that all such things were removed - `String` replaced with `CharSequences`...

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuffer.java#StringBuffer.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @Maksym: it's not describing, why there is this redundant constructor, the one with `String` do not need to be there...

Comment: "the one with String do not need to be there." Why ?

Comment: @Avin Very good question. Shows you correctly understand polymorphism and interfaces.

Comment: @Maksym: because while `String` implements `CharSequence` it matches with the first constructor... And the implementation is the same for both, so it's clear copy & paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) is an interface; it happens that `String` implements it.

This means that for instance, when you call `.charAt()` on a `String`, what is really called is the implementation of `String` for this method of `CharSequence`.

As you can see from the javadoc of `CharSequence`, not many classes in the JDK actually implement this interface.

As to why two constructors, `StringBuffer` dates back to Java 1.0 and `CharSequence` appears in 1.4 only; however, this is also the case that [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (which you should use, really, instead of `StringBuffer`) has two constructors (one with a `CharSequence` as an argument, another with a `String` as an argument), so there are probably optimizations implied when a `String` is passed as an argument. As to what such optimizations could be, well, it is a case of "Use The Source, Luke"(tm).

As an example of a `CharSequence` implementation which is not in the JDK, you can for example see one of my projects: [largetext](https://github.com/fge/largetext). Note that among other things, generating a `Matcher` from a `Pattern` [uses a `CharSequence` and not a `String` as an argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher-java.lang.CharSequence-); and since `String` implements `CharSequence`, well, passing a `String` as an argument works.

Comment: Your Post Cleared scenario little bit, But Why do we need charsequence and string argument both ? Isn't one of them are enough to demonstrate behavior of StringBuffer Constructor.

Comment: Sure, just the `CharSequence` constructor would suffice, but optimization is a perfectly good reason to have both.

Comment: What sort of example are you looking for?  I cant really tell what you're confused about.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I got your Answer but i was wondering that in which case optimization really matter ?(that example) Which one is good to use String or CharSequence ?

Comment: String has a fixed implementation with a char[] which can be copied more efficiently than an arbitrary CharSequence.

Comment: No, optimization is *not* the reason we have both. Polymorphism means the optimized implementation would automatically be used under the covers. @Avin, you correctly point out that we should not need both. As `String` is a `CharSequence`, we could simply pass a String instance to the method expecting a CharSequence instance. The reason we have both is because the early Java teams did not think this through thoroughly. The CharSequence interface was added much later, in Java 4 (1.4). So the signature expecting a String already existed.

Comment: @BasilBourque OK, but then why does `StringBuilder`, which is from 1.5, also have both constructors?

Comment: Ok,I got it and thank you for appreciation.@BasilBourque

Comment: @fge Dunno – certainly not technically needed. In Java 5, the pre-existing `StringBuffer` gained a new constructor for `CharSequence` to go along with its original constructor taking a `String`. Perhaps the Java 5 team wanted the new `StringBuilder` class to have a similar profile, and included the constructor taking a `String` despite being redundant with its constructor taking a `CharSequence`. They may have felt some of the millions of Java programmers may be confused by the lack of explicit `String` constructor. Source code of `StringBuilder` & `AbstactStringBuilder` holds no explanation.

Comment: Those confused by this assortment of text-related classes and their twisted history might find helpful  [my diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIFk9.png) in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26498954/642706) to the Question, [*Exact difference between CharSequence and String in java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11323962/642706).

Answer (score 5):

[`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) is an interface, so you cannot directly instantiate it. [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is a concrete class that implements the `CharSequence` interface. [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) also implements the `CharSequence` interface.

As for why `StringBuffer` has two constructors one that takes a `String` and one that takes a `CharSequence`, it is almost certainly because (per the `Since` line in the Javadoc) `CharSequence` was not added until Java v1.4 while `StringBuffer` (and `String`) were in Java 1.0

Answer (score 0):

**public StringBuffer(String str) :** Constructs a string buffer initialized to the contents of the specified string. The initial capacity of the string buffer is 16 plus the length of the string argument.

**public StringBuffer(CharSequence seq) :** Constructs a string buffer that contains the same characters as the specified CharSequence. The initial capacity of the string buffer is 16 plus the length of the CharSequence argument.
If the length of the specified CharSequence is less than or equal to zero, then an empty buffer of capacity 16 is returned.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuffer.java#StringBuffer.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I'm not sure, but that's what source code is saying.

Comment: That's why I do not like OpenJDK, who knows who added this comment, it's not in Oracle JDK...

Comment: Yeah, I tried hard to prove length can be < 0 (may be -1) but it is impossible.