# Initializing and using Interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, interface

First of all, I learned that:

- You cannot instantiate an Interface
- An Interface doesn't implement its functions

After seeing the following Java code:

```
public class MyClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // String to CharSequence?

        CharSequence c = "Java";

        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(c.length());
    }
}
```

I am very confused when I learned that `CharSequence` is an Interface

- How can you use an Interface like an object and initialize it?
- Why does `CharSequence` implements a `length` function if its an interface?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323962/exact-difference-between-charsequence-and-string-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"Java"` is an instance of the `String` class, which implements the `CharSequence` interface, which includes implementing the `length()` method. Therefore you can assign it to a `CharSequence` variable.

A variable whose type is an interface can be assigned references to instances (objects) of any classes that implement that interface.